# The best out-source tool for performance testing

Tags: performance-testing, open-source, load-testing

What is the best open-source tool, which has a graphical interface, for performance testing medium to large-scale web applications running in the cloud, using communication via HTTP, HTTPS, and gRPC, and is designed for 1000 concurrent users?

We are considering between JMeter, Artillery and Gatling.

Comment: although it is answered, I do not suggest you to follow that plugin, it only supports UNARY call, no streaming ability and it is NOT SUPPORT anymore (3 years without update), consider using Gatling using phiSgr's library because it is supported and updated regularly. No comment on Artillery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of listed tools only JMeter does have "graphical interface".

Out of the box JMeter doesn't support gRPC but there is a [plugin](https://github.com/zalopay-oss/jmeter-grpc-request) which enables the support, it can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager):

[image]